# Don't allow the user to create a folder if it's already exists using os module

Tags: python, user-interface, module, duplicates, operating-system

I am trying to make a add course form ,in which admin will write course name in textbox then folder will be create of that name.But if the course is already exists then it sends an error message like "course is already exists" . Here is what I tried

```
string=tk.StringVar()
label1=tk.Label(frame,text="Enter Course Name:",font=20,bg="#33BEFF")
label1.place(relx=0.25,rely=0.27)
coursetxt=ttk.Entry(frame,textvariable=string,text="")
coursetxt.place(relx=0.52,rely=0.27)

def addcourse():
    name=coursetxt.get()
    conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};''Server=SHUMAILA\SHUM;''Database=FYP;''Trusted_Connection=yes;')
    cursor=conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('insert into course(cname)values(?)',(name))
    courses_f=os.chdir('G:\Shumaila\FYP\FYP\courses')  #path where course folder are saved
    course_folder=os.mkdir(name)  #for creating course folder
    if course_folder.path.exists in courses_f:
        messagebox.showinfo("Message","Course is already exist")
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo("Message","Course is added")
        course_folder=os.mkdir(name)


addbutton=tk.Button(frame,text="Add",bg='#FF6E33',command=addcourse)
addbutton['font']=myFont
addbutton.place(relx=0.40,rely=0.35,relwidth=0.20,relheight=0.10)
```

after running the code it gives me this error

```
FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'E1'
where E1 is the name of course I entered in textbox
```

and I want that this message  will print in a messagebox .

I also try this but it's also not working

```
     if name in os.chdir('G:\Shumaila\FYP\FYP\courses'):
        messagebox.showinfo("Message","Course is already exist")
     else:
        os.mkdir(name)
        messagebox.showinfo("Message","Course is added")
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's talk about `os.mkdir()`.

`mkdir` creates a directory with the given path. If the path is relative, it will create it relative to the current working directory. I would avoid that, and use the full path.

(Why? Because the current working directory is a global, and changing it may affect other parts of the code.)

`mkdir`always returns None.

So, wen you call `course_folder=os.mkdir(name)`, you are just setting course_folder to None.

When you reference `course_folder.path` that doesn't exist.

---

Let's talk about `os.chdir()`.

`chdir` changes the current working directory.

The current working directory is only relevant when you are using relative paths. You should probably just use full paths, and never change it.

`chdir`always returns None.

So when you set `courses_f=os.chdir([whatever])` you are setting `courses_f` to None.

Similarly when you check if `name in os.chdir([whatever])`, you are just checking for `name in None`.

---

How should you solve it?

You could use `os.path.exists()` to check whether there is a (folder or file) with that name already, *before* calling `os.mkdir()`.

That might have a race condition (someone else could create the file between the two calls), so a better way might be to try to create it, and catch the exception if it fails.

Comment: thankyou so much! i tried it and it's working. i post the code you may check it

Answer (score 0):

here what i done and it is working.

```
def addcourse():
    name=coursetxt.get()
    conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};''Server=SHUMAILA\SHUM;''Database=FYP;''Trusted_Connection=yes;')
    cursor=conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('insert into course(cname)values(?)',(name))
    os.chdir
    if os.path.exists(name):
        messagebox.showinfo("Message","Course is already exist")
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo("Message","Course is added")
        os.mkdir(name)
```

Comment: `os.chdir` doesn't do anything. (There are no parameters.) I can't tell if `name` is the full path, or relative. If it is relative, then the directory is being created in wherever the current working directory happens to be.